# Check if function has multiple arguments in module.exports

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'd like to do something like:

```
module.exports = (obj) => {
   if (arguments.length > 1) {
     throw new Error('Must only pass in single argument');
   }
}
```

When I log the arguments, I get meta data about about the module itself and can not see the argument that was passed in. Is there a way I can check if additional arguments were passed in?

Here's my test:

```
it('should reject multiple arguments', () => {
  expect(fn({ data: 1}, { data: 2})).to.throw(Error, 'Too many inputs');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MDN's page on arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) notes:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own `this`, **`arguments`**, `super`, or `new.target`.

In other words, to check if an arrow function gets more arguments than it expects, using `arguments` does not work (as it would with a normal function), so you should use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
const fn = (obj, ...restArgs) => {
  if(restArgs.length > 0) {
    // got more arguments than expected
    throw new Error('Must only pass in single argument');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`arguments` doesn't work with ES6 arrow functions.
Try this `...args`

```
function f(a, b, ...args) {

}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 0):

As other people mentioned, arrow function is the cause of your problem.

However, using rest args is not a good solution in order to properly define your API in this case.

To remain compatible to what you want (showing the function takes only one argument), you should do:

```
module.exports = function (obj) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    throw new Error('Must only pass in single argument');
  }
}
```

In your arrow function, argument is actually tied to something you are not expected.
See https://github.com/unional/some-issues/tree/so-arrow-arguments for what it actually does.

Comment: *"However, using rest args is not a good solution in order to properly define your API."* Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: Because `function (obj, ...restArgs) { ... }` suggests that this function is taking `...restArgs`, while the objective is to prohibit that. i.e. the API is conflicting with the intent.